# VBA [classes] - how to access a previously instanciated instance of a class in another sub

Tags: oop, vba

I've created the instance "Lassie" of the class "Dog" within a particular sub in my program. I have also given it some useful properties, such as Lassie.Age = 7 and Lassie.HeelCapability = False.

Now I would like to access **another** sub and change the Lassie.HeelCapability to True.
How do I go about defining the instance "Lassie" within this new sub so it can be worked with?

All the code I have come accross goes like this:

```
Dim Lassie As classDog

Set Lassie = New classDog
```

Essentially what I am looking for is a way to import the existing instance "Lassie" into another sub, without using the keyword "New" and thereby creating a new "Lassie" (without all the properties previously given).

The errormessages I have been receiving tell me either "object required" or "object variable or with block variable not set".

Surely there is a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass 'Lassie' as a parameter to your other sub.

```
public sub DeclareSub()
  Dim Lassie as classDog
  Lassie = new classDog

  OtherSub Lassie
end sub

public sub OtherSub(ByRef dog as classDog) 

end sub
```

The variable 'dog' in the subroutine 'OtherSub' refers to the same object instance as the variable 'Lassie' from 'DeclareSub'.

Comment: +1 for a mostly correct answer to a new VBA programmer's question. I edited your answer, though. With object references, it doesn't matter whether you pass them `ByVal` or `ByRef` when it comes to changes made to the underlying object. `OtherSub` can change the instance of `classDog` it is passed even if it is passed `ByVal`. In this case what `ByVal` would do is prevent `OtherSub` from `Set`ting the parameter `dog` to a different instance of `classDog`.

Comment: @jtolle Thank you for the clarification. You learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object in `ByRef` to your new Subroutine.

```
Sub ChangeHeel(ByRef olassie As classDog)
    'change the object here, and it will be changed in the calling sub
    olassie.HeelCapability = True
End Sub
```

Comment: See my comment to keytarhero's answer, but the ByRef doesn't really matter here...