# vba: Dictionary passed to function acting as "ByRef" when forced as "ByVal"

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dictA` that contains `{AA,1},{AB,2},{AC,3}` and an adjustment dictionary `dictAdj` containing `{AB,-4}`.

I pass these two into a function call it `funcReconcile(ByVal Arg1 as Dictionary, ByVal Arg2 as Dictionary) as Dictionary`.

The function is going to loop through the contents of dictAdj to see if they exist in dictA.

The function will then adjust dictA (for example) to show `{AA,1},{AB,-2},{AC,3}` in the output dictionary.

For some reason, when the function returns the dictionary, my original `dictA` is also effected, causing it to display `{AA,1},{AB,-2},{AC,3}` and not `{AA,1},{AB,4},{AC,3}` as it should.

I know there are issues in VBA with passing ByRef and ByVal for objects, but this is the first time really hitting my head against the wall with something like this.

Any pointers? (no pun intended)

Comment: Dictionary is a reference type.  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: any way to force it or lock it? i even recast to a new variable inside the function. no luck. also this is vba...not C#

Comment: You need to manually copy the dictionary.

Comment: jason, see my comment on this answer for more information about what @SLaks is talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697105/vba-classes-how-to-access-a-previously-instanciated-instance-of-a-class-in-a/6697237#comment7926759_6697237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to build a copy method, make a complete copy of the dictionary, and then make modifications on the copy.

Assigning to a new variable just assigns the original reference to the new variable -- which points back to the original data.

Here's some fragmentary code from [Copy from one dictionary object into another?](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1420195):

```
a=dictionary1.items
b=dictionary1.keys
for i=0 to ubound(a)
  dictionary2.add(b(i), a(i))
next
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is really old, it may not help the original poster.  I came across this while researching the same.  My solution (I believe) is better.  It uses linq instead of a loop which saves resources.  My code is in vb as that's what my project is using, but you can use a code converter to change the function.

Simple 1 line solution.  2 separate dictionaries that are true copies (separate identities):

```
Dim dictionary2 As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = dictionary1.ToDictionary(Function(k) k.Key, Function(k) k.Value.ToString())
```

Comment: Really old answer... but that's VB.NET code, and the question is (was?) about VBA... and thus isn't applicable.

Comment: That is correct.  Unfortunately it has been more than 3 years, I cannot explain why I missed this.  I had just graduated (May-13), so I'm going to have to go with I tried and incorrectly answered.